# Perl - how to call Oracle DB stored procedure

Tags: oracle, perl

I'm attempting to execute a stored procedure and (for now) get the number of rows returned.
But I keep getting the following error:

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: OCI
StmtExecute) [for Statement "exec VSU22.DB_API.GetUsersInfo(?);" with ParamValue
s: :p1=1] at C:\NNInstall\auit.pl line 19.
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use dbi;

my ($connection_string, $nn_dbh, $extract_sth);
my $dbIPAddress = "192.168.147.55";
my @row;
my $query_result=0;
my $var;
$connection_string = "dbi:Oracle:host=$dbIPAddress;sid=NNVSDB";
$nn_dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
$nn_dbh->{RowCacheSize} = 256;
$nn_dbh = DBI->connect($connection_string, 'DBSUER', 'DBUSER')
    or die "Connection failed: $DBI::errstr";

$extract_sth = $nn_dbh->prepare('exec DBUSER.API.UsersInfo(?);');
$extract_sth ->bind_param(1, 1);
my $num_ofOrows= $extract_sth->execute();
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Do you know that the stored proc executes correctly?  Have you tested it in Oracle?  2. If so, do you know if the param is being passed in the format expected?  Can you get the proc to output the sql statement created either to console or to a temp table to verify that the sql statement is being built correctly in the stored proc?  3. It would be useful to post the stored proc code too.

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. The expected parameter type is a NUMBER.
3. I cannot post the procedure code.

Comment: Ok. I would find a way to output the sql created on the sp to see if that statement fails. If not, then its the call that's failing - but at least you know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC[CUTE]` is a [SQL*Plus command](http://ss64.com/ora/exec.html). It's normally not implemented in other SQL clients. You probably need to use an anonymous PL/SQL block;

```
BEGIN
    DBUSER.API.UsersInfo(?);
END;
```

Comment: Should I do the same if for 'CALL DBUSER.API.USERSINFO(?);' ?

Comment: But what about the error I'm getting? I've added the BEGIN & END but I get the same error.

Comment: To be honest I've answered this question from my PHP experience. I don't know if there're Perl specifics involved. I don't have an Oracle box to test it right now but both an anonymous block and the `CALL` operator should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Oracle XE in a Docker container and using their sample database.

Here's a stored procedure that takes a parameter and returns a set of records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE customer_orders(cust_id IN NUMBER, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN cur FOR 
        SELECT * 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE customer_id = cust_id; 
end;
/
```

Here's the Perl that executes the procedure, passing the customer id as a parameter, and processing the returned results set.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);
 
# get the database connection
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:localhost/xepdb1", "ot", "Orcl1234") || die(DBI->errstr());

$sth = $dbh->prepare("BEGIN customer_orders(?, ?); END;");

$sth->bind_param(1, 49);

$sth->bind_param_inout(2, \$rsh, 0, {ora_type => ORA_RSET});

$sth->execute();

while ( @row = $rsh->fetchrow_array ){
    foreach ( @row ){
        print "$_\t";
    };
    print "\n";
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

I hope this saves all who pass this way the time it took me to figure it out.

Luck.